# Sync Framework stuck on Synchronize()

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I have this simple application that syncs 2 databases on 2 tables, thing is, after provisioning and deprovisioning, I am stuck in the `Synchronize()` method. It doesn't throw any errors, SQL Profiler has thrown the `Audit Logout` event class.

This is on a microsoft service and when looking at it's process, it's still using 400mb of Memory, along with sqlserver.exe. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

how long has it been stucked and how big are the changes you're trying to sync.

you should enable Sync Fx tracing so you know where is it at.

it should be stuck there forever as eventually the SQL Commands will time out.